# Deliver app_review_information command line

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

How can I use the `--app_review_information` parameter from the command line?

The documentation says:

> --app_review_information Metadata: A hash containing the review information

How can I hash the contact info as command line param?

I don't use `Deliverfile`.

Any example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have looked a bit in the source files and I didn't notice any `String` to `Hash` conversion when executed from the command line... You could use a script that 1) generates a throwaway `Deliverfile` with the review information, 2) runs deliver, 3) removes the `Deliverfile`.

Comment: You should probably ping Felix, the author, on Twitter https://twitter.com/krausefx

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Create a Deliverfile with just the app_review_information, fastlane will use what is in the Deliverfile and the others parameters in the command.